# LateInitializationError: Field '_amount@25125456' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do some tax calculation in my flutter project but, It is giving me two errors.

1. LateInitializationError: Field '_amount@25125456' has not been initialized.
2. Error: The operator '~/' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
   Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '~/' operator.

I am not sure why it is happening can anyone please help me out?

// this is my function

```
showincomeafterTax() {
if (_amount!.isNotEmpty) {
  taxamount = (_amount * 17 ~/ 100).toString();
  print(taxamount);
} else {
  print('Insert an amount');
}
```

}

// designing part

```
 Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Income after Tax',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.monetization_on_outlined),
                      title: showincomeafterTax(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is kinda clear:

**Error 1.** Your variable `_amount` has not been initialized. You may declare you variable as

> late String _amount;

But you hasn't assign/initiate it to any value, therefore your program gives the first error.

**Error 2.** `_amount` is String type, you cannot use it in a math like a number. I notice that you use operator `~/`, which is used in integer. So you need to convert String to a int, example:

```
if (_amount!.isNotEmpty) {
  int amountDouble = int.parse(_amount);
  taxamount = (amountDouble * 17 ~/ 100).toString();
  print(taxamount);
} else {
  print('Insert an amount');
}
```

Comment: I already initiated late String _amount; as global variable. If you want I have share full code on  https://codeshare.io/1YAkdz

Comment: That is DECLARE, not INITIATE. You have to assign _amount to a value.

Comment: Such as: `String _amount = "";`